# How to say "to lend or give voice to"?

Tags: english-to-german

I want to translate the following sentence from I. Asimov's, I, Robot:

> Gloria gasped and panted, and gave voice to intermittent whispered exclamations of “That was nice!”

Does this work?

> Gloria keuchte und hechelte und **verlieh eine Stimme zu** unterbrochenen, geflüsterten Ausrufen: »Das war nett!«.

Comment: The sentence is already somewhat lacking in the original; e.g. *exclamation* implies an intensity if not even loud volume, which mismatches *whispering*. I'm not sure whether *that was nice* qualifies as *exclamation* at all. I strongly favour a free translation to bypass these issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't quite fit as cited.

[Google translate](https://translate.google.com/?sl=auto&tl=de&text=Gloria%20gasped%20and%20panted%2C%20and%20gave%20voice%20to%20intermittent%20whispered%20exclamations%20of%20%E2%80%9CThat%20was%20nice!&op=translate) gives

> Gloria keuchte und keuchte und gab zeitweilig geflüsterte Ausrufe von sich: "Das war schön!"

[DeepL translates](https://www.deepl.com/translator#en/de/Gloria%20gasped%20and%20panted%2C%20and%20gave%20voice%20to%20intermittent%20whispered%20exclamations%20of%20%E2%80%9CThat%20was%20nice!) it as

> Gloria keuchte und keuchte und stieß immer wieder geflüsterte Ausrufe aus wie "Das war schön!"

The translation by DeepL is quite good and accurate, Google is so-so (especially the 'zeitweilig' does not really fit. The sentence structure change is ok, but I don't like it).

You can lend your voice to someone or something - but that does not seem to fit here - nor does that English expression seem to fit the context of this sentence: no weight or emphasis is given on behalf of anything or anyone. It is just a statement about personal emotions.

to lend your voice to sth/sb: seine Stimme einer Sache / Person verleihen
This means to get engaged oneself in an argument on behalf of another person or a greater cause, possibly because ones own influence is larg(er) and one has more impact than other people.

As such, if you insist on a similar expression, there is "einer Sache Ausdruck verleihen". In this case she expresses emotions, so the sentence needs to be slightly changed to utilize this:

> Gloria keuchte und hechelte und verlieh ihren Emotionen Ausdruck mit gelegentlichen geflüsterten Ausrufen von "Das war klasse!".

Perhaps "ihrer Aufregung" is more fitting than "ihren Emotionen". Depends on context.

(Unrelated to the question, yet: from the context given, "nett" is probably a too emotionless translation of "nice". "Toll" or "klasse" seem to fit better).

Comment: I looked up the sentence in my German edition of "I, Robot" (the story is "Robbie"), and disappointingly, it is simply: _Gloria schnappte nach Luft. "Das war schön", schnaufte sie._.

Comment: I think this answer would better if it didn't inlude the online service translations (I don't see the point why they should be there in the first place). Anyway, +1